# grep -E with parameter doesn't work

Tags: bash, shell-script, grep

If I use `-E` option for `grep` from a script I'm unable to user variables.
For example:

txt file:

```
word
nir asd b asd
text
```

script:

```
#!/bin/bash

PARAM=b
cat txt | grep -E 'nir.*${PARAM}'
```

The script return nothing. I guess with `-E` option I need to escape the variable somehow.

Comment: That is "useless use of cat".

Comment: It's just a small example for you to understand the real problem, e.g the `grep`. The `"` solved it, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
PARAM=b
grep -E "nir.*${PARAM}" txt
```

or

```
grep -E 'nir.*'"${PARAM}" txt
```